# variable populated through useSelector (redux) displaying null instead of actual value when accessing through Sencha button handler

Tags: reactjs, extjs, react-redux, extreact

variable populated through useSelector (redux) displaying null instead of actual value when accessing through button handler. when using the class-based approach it works fine:

```
import React from "react";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Button } from "@sencha/ext-react-modern";

const LoadButton = () => {
  const viewer = useSelector((state) => state.bim._viewer);

  const handleSenchaBtn = () => {
    console.log("sencha button", viewer);
  };
  const handleHtmlBtn = () => {
    console.log("html button", viewer);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleHtmlBtn}>Normal Button</button>
      <Button text="Sencha Button" ui="action" handler={handleSenchaBtn} />
    </>
  );
};

export default LoadButton;
```

Console logs of button actions:

[image: Console logs]